# IE8 HTMLMediaElement play() shim

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js, shim

The following code plays sound in IE9+ (and in Firefox and Chrome as well). Is there a library that implements/polyfills missing features (`audio` element and `play()` method) for IE8?

I couldn't make `mediaelement.js` working, and using jQuery or putting `<object>` inside `<audio>` seems ugly. Some global initialization (like `shim.init(somepath)`) to let the shim find its flash files is fine, but per-tag code looks wrong to me as it should be possible to automate.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo()
        {
            var audio = document.getElementById('foo')
            audio.play()    
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="foo" preload="none">
        <source src="foo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source src="foo.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <button onclick="foo()">Play</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with placing `object` inside `audio`. According to spec "Content may be provided inside the audio element. User agents should not show this content to the user; it is intended for older Web browsers which do not support audio, so that legacy audio plugins can be tried ...".

Comment: I know it's standard-compliant. That's why I called it's ugly. It's ugly because it is unnecessary in compliant browsers and can be auto-inserted by the shim. The concept of shim is that I can assume my browser is compliant even if it isn't, and I don't have to sprinkle statements related to fixing non-compliance across my code. The <object> is precisely such sprinkling. So basically I'm asking to what extend it's possible to have a shim <audio> tag, as opposed to mere cross-platform support.

Comment: Why it's offtopic? It is a question about a possibility of a shim.

Answer (score 0):

You can make MEJS work without needing an additional library (but jQuery) or polyfills in IE[7-8] and without adding an `object` tag within the `audio` tag.

The workaround is to create a *global* object within the `success` setting, that can be used by IE before using the `.play()` ( ... or `.pause()` ) method(s)

So, having this simple html

```
<audio id="myAudioPlayer" src="media/audio.mp3" preload="none"></audio>

<button onclick="audioPlay();">Play</button> 
<button onclick="audioPause();">Pause</button> <!-- optional -->
```

You could use this code :

```
var audio; // global object to be used by IE (and all browsers as a matter of fact)
var isPlaying = false; // flag for event listeners

function audioPlay() {
    // only call play() method if audio is not playing
    // avoids multiple playbacks in IE
    if (!isPlaying) {
        audio.play();
        isPlaying = true;
    }
};

function audioPause() {
    // only call pause() method if audio is playing
    if (isPlaying) {
        audio.pause();
        isPlaying = false;
    }
};

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer("#myAudioPlayer", {
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            audio = mediaElement; // set value to global object to be used outside the success setting by IE
            // event listeners so we only call our functions when needed 
            audio.addEventListener('playing', function () {
                isPlaying = true;
            }, false);
            audio.addEventListener('pause', function () {
                isPlaying = false;
            }, false);
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** we added a couple of *event* listeners so we call our methods only when needed (and avoid multiple playbacks in IE)

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6EcQb/)**

**NOTE**

This code is for `audio` elements. `Video` elements may require other workarounds.